# How to delete specific blank line and concat two line in a text file?

Tags: python

I have an existing txt file(test1) like that,

```
line1
line2

supp-linex

line3

supp-linex
line4
line5
```

I want to find the line with "supp" and add this line directly behind the previous line like,(others blank line is not change)

```
line1
line2linex

line3linex
line4
line5
```

I know less about how to tackling txt file so in this code,

```
a_file = open("test1.txt", "r")
lines = a_file.readlines()
a_file.close()

new_file = open("test2.txt", "w")
for line in lines:
    if "supp" in line:
        #del blank and concat line,I dont know how to del and concat in detail
new_file.write(lines)
new_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way that does it without a new list

```
a_file = open("test.txt", "r")
lines = a_file.readlines()
a_file.close()

new_file = open("test2.txt", "w")

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if "supp" in line:
        j = i
        while lines[j-1] == "\n":
            del(lines[j-1])
            j -= 1
        
        lines[j-1] = lines[j-1].strip() + line.strip("supp-")
        del(lines[j])

for line in lines:
    new_file.write(line)
new_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a new list to save the result.

```
with open("test1.txt") as f:
  a_file = f.read().splitlines()

b_file = []
for line in a_file:
  if line.startswith('supp-'):
    # Removes previous empty lines if possible.
    while b_file and len(b_file[-1]) == 0:
      b_file.pop()
    if b_file:
      # Concatenate previous line
      b_file[-1] += line[5:]
    else:
      # When there's no previous lines, appends as is
      b_file.append(line[5:])
  else:
    b_file.append(line)

with open('test2.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write('\n'.join(b_file) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re` (*regular expression*) [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) in Python's standard library to find the pattern and replace it via module's [`sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function. To help understand how it works, think of the contents of the whole text file as a single long string containing this:

```
"line1\nline2\n\nsupp-linex\n\nline3\n\nsupp-linex\nline4\nline5\n"
```

The regular expression pattern shown in the code below matches a line of characters followed by a blank line, then another prefixed with literal string `"supp-"`. The groups of characters from the match group are also assigned the names `prev` and `extra` so they can easily be referred to in the replacement text. The substitution process is applied to the whole file with one `sub()` call, and then the result of that gets written out to the second text file.

**Note:** There's a really good [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) in the onliinr documentation.

```
import re

with open('test1.txt', 'r') as a_file:
    lines = a_file.read()

pattern = r'''(?P<prev>.+)\n\nsupp-(?P<extra>.+)\n'''
replacement = r'''\g<prev>\g<extra>\n'''

with open('test2.txt', 'w') as new_file:
    result = re.sub(pattern, replacement, lines)
    new_file.write(result)

print('fini')
```

Here's the contents of `test2.txt` after running:

```
line1
line2linex

line3linex
line4
line5
```